# Regex parsing - how to filter two words in a file

Tags: regex

I have an output that i would like parsed: example:

```
License 1: IPx3
Type: Permanent

Licence 2: UCS
Type: Permanent 

Licence 3: Avi
Type: Unknown
```

I want to be able to for each license, get its name and type. I tried using this `/(ipx3?|Permanent)/gim` but it shows output of all Permanent for all the other license types but I want for only each license type. Is this possible with Regex?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need regex for this, why not just split the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `(Licen[sc]e\s*?\d+):\s*?(\w+|d+])\s*?(Type):\s*?(\w+)`

if you don't know how much there would be whitespaces -  `\s*?` 
 if you know that there will be only 1, can be used `\s`

- group 1 - license
- group 2 - name
- group 4 - type

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/v6LCM0/1)